# What should I do if the discord bot sends more and more messages every time?

Tags: python, discord, bots

I wanted to write a program for the discord bot so that when a new participant enters, he welcomes him and gives him a role, but with each newcomer, the bot sends +1 the same message how to fix it?
the code is left below:

```
import disnake
from disnake.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.', help_command=None, intents=disnake.Intents.all())



@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Bot {bot.user} is ready to work')


@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    role = disnake.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id=id)
    channel = bot.get_channel(id)

    embed = disnake.Embed(
        title='новый участник',
        description=f'{member.name}#{member.discriminator}',
        color=0xFFFFFF
    )


    await member.add_roles(role)
    await channel.send(embed=embed)
   

bot.run('token')
```